# underscore with 2 variables

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am trying to add a variable on my script like this:

```
ssh root@$dev 'cat /etc/hosts > /var/tmp/hosts_$dev_$(date +%F)'
```

But, this does not work, I tried with

```
/var/tmp/hosts\_$dev\_$(date +%F)'
/var/tmp/hosts_${dev}_$(date +%F)'
```

Can someone please help me  the output will still be no matter what I do.

```
hosts_2017-06-20
```

Resolution for future use:

I used single quotes instead of double quotes like this:

```
ssh root@$dev "cat /etc/hosts > /var/tmp/hosts\_$dev\_$(date +%F)"
```

Comment: your problem is the variable `dev` is not defined.

Comment: it is defined that ssh is inside a for loop that reads the IP address from a file

Comment: No; You problem is that you are using SINGLE QUOTES, and this will preserve the literal value of that sentence, not the content of `$dev`. Try to use double quotes instead - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash

Comment: Also exec ssh on this way: `ssh -o dev=$dev`

Comment: @nwilder Yes! that was it.... the single quotes.

Comment: posted as an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me [quote this wonderful question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/2231796) with it's selected answer, to avoid explaining again something that was already answered on other site of stackexchange. This is the section of [`bash(1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) manpage related to variable quoting:

> [3.1.2.2 Single Quotes](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Single-Quotes.html)
>
> Enclosing characters in single quotes (`'`) preserves the literal value of each character within the quotes. A single quote may not occur between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.
>
> [3.1.2.3 Double Quotes](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html)
>
> Enclosing characters in double quotes (`"`) preserves the literal value of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of `$`, `` ` ``, `\`, and, when history expansion is enabled, `!`. The characters `$` and `` ` `` retain their special meaning within double quotes (see [Shell Expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html#Shell-Expansions)). The backslash retains its special meaning only when followed by one of the following characters: `$`, `` ` ``, `"`, `\`, or newline. Within double quotes, backslashes that are followed by one of these characters are removed. Backslashes preceding characters without a special meaning are left unmodified. A double quote may be quoted within double quotes by preceding it with a backslash. If enabled, history expansion will be performed unless an `!` appearing in double quotes is escaped using a backslash. The backslash preceding the `!` is not removed.
>
> The special parameters `*` and `@` have special meaning when in double quotes (see [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)).

**Answer:** That is why on your destination file you had `$dev` instead of the contents of that variable.